# GCC 4.9.0 is required to build WebKitGTK+

Tags: gcc, webkit

The title says it all. I forked webkit and want to build it Before I start making changes. But I get that error.

```
gcc (Ubuntu 4.9.3-8ubuntu2~14.04) 4.9.3
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Is the result of gcc --version so i don't know why it does this. Can anybody shine a little light on the subject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I figured it out. Somewhere, it has a list of failed prerequisites I guess, so I had to redownload the source and it worked.